# Raspberry PI Zero W - CentOS How configure WiFi Headless

Tags: pi-zero-w

I'm big fan of CentOS and so far using CentOS happily on Pi 3. But recently I bought Pi Zero W and now I want to configure it to connect to my home Wifi. But yet to figure out how to configure Wifi headless. I know how to do it if I have wired connection. But I'm after a solution which I don't have to rely on wired solution.

Have anybody done something like this? Or else I'm excited to try out any option if you can think of.(so far I have only wired options)

Comment: if you are using the same network, then you could fresh install setup your wifi then resize your drive using gparted running in virtualbox then create a new image using win32diskimager. I have a tutorial on resizing [link](https://steemit.com/raspberrypi/@wizzle/shrink-raspberry-pi-images-using-windows-virtualbox-running-raspberry-pi-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

The question should be reworded to clarify **exactly** what you are asking.  The current wording is ambiguous. You seem to indicate that you can't find documentation for getting CentOS connected via wireless on your PI Zero?  Do you already have CentOS (or some variant of it) running on your PI?

CentOS does not support the ARMv6 architecture, which is what the PI Zero and PI 1 use.  Fedora is similar to CentOS, and there is a third-party Fedora port for PI called [Pignus](https://pignus.computer/index.html).  This explicitly supports ARMv6.  If you wish to install a CentOS-like OS, take a look at this.  It is still in Alpha release.  It should be noted that this is not considered stable and should not be used for production systems.

For getting the standard headless Jessie Lite up and running, take a look at 
[this website](https://medium.com/@danidudas/install-raspbian-jessie-lite-and-setup-wi-fi-without-access-to-command-line-or-using-the-network-97f065af722e).  Basically you need to edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` using a text editor (vi/nano) with sudo permissions. Append this to the wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
network={
   ssid="Your Network SSID"
   psk="Your Network Password"
}
```

I'm assuming that you have some decent technical experience because you are not running a default config/OS on your PI 3, otherwise I would have given more explicit instruction.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm, in particular, looking for CentOS and Pi Zero W. Pi Zero W is with ARM11 and I think it should be compatible with CentOS. Corect me if I'm wrong. Now the actual question here is I don't have a monitor (headless) nor key board. The configuration you suggested is only possible with a key board and a monitor.